# Is it possible to cancel current partial function from function body?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, partialfunction

I need to define some partial functions to handle different urls with different patterns (with unfinagled):

```
def indexRoute:PartialFunction[Request, Response] = { 
   case Path("index") => Ok ~> ResponseString("hello")
}

def notFound:PartialFunction[Request, Response] = { 
    case Path(_) => NotFound
}

def assetsRoutes:PartialFunction[Request, Response] = { 
    case Path("assets" :: tail) =>
      loadResourceContent(tail) match {
          case Some(content) => Ok ~> ResponseString(content)
          case _ => NotFound // !!! I don't want to handle it here
      }
}

val allRoutes = indexRoute orElse assetsRoutes orElse notFound
```

You can see I combined some partial functions into a complete routes in the end. The last one is `NotFound` which is handling the unmatched urls, so I don't want to care the unmatching cases in earlier routes (say, `assertRoutes`).

But in the `assetsRoutes` method, I can't easily check if the asset exists or not in the `case` part, because I want only touch the file system once for a asset. So I don't want to write:

```
def assetsRoutes:PartialFunction[Request, Response] = { 
    case Path("assets" :: tail) if resoueceExist(tail)=>
      val content = loadResourceContent(tail).get 
      Ok ~> ResponseString(content)
}
```

Although I can write a custom `unapply` like:

```
object AssetExistWithContent {

  def unapply(req:Request): Option[String] =  {
    req match {
      case Path("assets" :: tail) => loadResourceContent(tail)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}

def assetsRoutes:PartialFunction[Request, Response] = { 
    case AssetExistWithContent(content) => Ok ~> ResponseString(content)
}
```

But I think it's not clear to see the `case AssetExistWithContent(content)` part when matching the url or a request.

So I wonder is it possible to cancel current partial function in function body? So I can write:

```
def assetsRoutes:PartialFunction[Request, Response] = { 
    case Path("assets" :: tail) =>
      loadResourceContent(tail) match {
          case Some(content) => Ok ~> ResponseString(content)
          case _ => cancelThisPartialFunction // !!!
      }
}
```

That I don't need to care when to do in this method (NotFound or other things), just tell the caller that I can't handle it, please try next one.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to cancel a `PartialFunction` as you are describing. However, you could define a simpler extractor:

```
object LoadableContent {
  def unapply(req: List[String]): Option[String] = loadResourceContent(req)
}
```

and use it like:

```
def assetsRoutes: PartialFunction[Request, Response] = { 
    case Path("assets" :: LoadableContent(content)) =>
      Ok ~> ResponseString(content)
}
```